# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR -Vue.js deployed on IIS10

Tags: vue.js, iis-10

[image]    /css//SchoolSystem~9d2cc99c.8ec07234.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
/css/UsersAnnouncements~db460838.0e433876.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
/css/DashboardComponent~10c63b4c.bc5d4d1b.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
chunk-vendors~575de10d.881773f3.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Getting above error for all the component when doing a refresh by using ctrl+f5 and the website does not render and doing again a refresh from browser it renders.
This is happening more when I used

```
optimization: {
          splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all",
            minSize: 30000,
            maxSize: 400000,
```

split Chunk to split the vendor chunk in small size, its doing that and all are injected in the Index.html file which is automatically done by webpack.
Now unable to understand that in which direction should I go for searching. before splitting the vendor...js file the site was loading very slow now its not loading at all.

Comment: Try to disable http/2 on IIS and access site agian. It seems that http/2 caused this issue. Can you determine the correct url of these css files?

Comment: Hello Bruce, Can I do something in vue.js to fix this issue

Comment: I'm not an expert on vue, so what I can provide is suggestions on IIS.

Comment: Please Bruce, any suggestion on IIS would be fine, so that I can move forward - Its deployed on IIS 10 on Windows 16 server standard.

Comment: Have you tried the first comment to disable http/2 on IIS? Set it in bindings https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXBta.png

Comment: @BruceZhang, have checked the binding of my site, but it does not have the 2 options, The version of the IIS is 10.0.14393.0 on windows 16 server. Do I need to upgrade IIS ?

Comment: No need to update IIS. Can you show the screenshoot of it?

Comment: @BruceZhang, Have added the screenshot in the Question itself, was not getting option in comment.

Comment: You can open regedit and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters. Then add EnableHttp2Tls and EnableHttp2Cleartext under parameter. Set both values are 0 and restart machine.